# Store URL Parameter as String Variable ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using ASP.NET MVC and I have a URL that looks like this `/Application/Errors/DependingWhichHyperlinkClicked` The last parameter is passed to the URL through this code `<a href="@Url.Action("Errors", new { id=item.Application})"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Application) </a>` I want to take the last part of the URL and store that in a variable. This variable will then be used in a LINQ query in order to display results matching the final parameter of the URL.  The final parameter can change depending on which hyperlink is clicked as I am wanting to show different results on different pages.

I would think the code would look something along the lines of this but I may be wrong...

```
var queryString = ...
var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                           where s.Application == queryString
                           select s;
```

I am just unsure what to write in order for the `queryString` variable to take in the URL parameter. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your click handler or page load?

Comment: this is how I pass the parameter to the url `<a href="@Url.Action("Errors", new { id=item.Application})"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Application) </a>`

Comment: Could you answer with one sentence what exactly you can't do ? You want to take DependingWhichHyperlinkClicked ? There is string.Split, there is Request["ParamName"], Request[index]

Comment: so you are using mvc?

Comment: correct, Ill edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: just add an `string id` argument to your action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using default routing then you can use [RouteData.Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.values(v=vs.110).aspx) property:-

```
RouteData.Values["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say "yourUrl" contains : "/Application/Errors/DependingWhichHyperlinkClicked"

This is the easy solution :

```
var splited = yourUrl.Split('/');
var queryString = splited.last();
```

You could also extract the final parameter with a RegEx :

```
var queryString = Regex.Match(yourUrl, @"\/Application\/Errors\/(.*)").Groups[1];
```

This option is "safer" (for example, if you have a / in your parameter, the split will return only the last part of the parameter), but you will have to improve my basic regex.